# Check multiple values on each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, for-loop

I am stuck on this problem. I am trying to assign a priority score based on location. If location column contains Beirut or Saida prioity score =1. If location column contains Baalbeck or Sour priority score =2.Else priority score =3. The problem is that the location row can contain multiple locations.

Dataframe example:

Business  Location
X.    Beirut,Aley
Y.    Saida,Sour
Z.    Baalbeck,Tripoli
D.    Tripoli

Desired Output:

```
Business  Location.     Score
    X.    Beirut,Aley.   1
    Y.    Saida,Sour.     1
    Z.    Baalbeck,Tripoli 2
    D.    Tripoli.          3
```

I tried to use str.contains in the location column but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a generic method, I would use a dictionary of words and a regex match:

```
priority = {1: ['Beirut', 'Saida'], 2: ['Baalbeck', 'Sour']}

import re
import numpy as np
patterns = {'|'.join(map(re.escape, l)): i for i, l in priority.items()}
# {'Beirut|Saida': 1, 'Baalbeck|Sour': 2}

df['Score'] = np.select([df['Location'].str.contains(pat, case=False)
                         for pat in patterns],
                        patterns.values(), 3)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Business          Location  Score
0       X.      Beirut,Aley.      1
1       Y.       Saida,Sour.      1
2       Z.  Baalbeck,Tripoli      2
3       D.          Tripoli.      3
```